# extracting binary data from xml file and convert to image

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to extract some binary data from an xml file and convert it to an image.  I hardcoded the xml data into my source code to simplify my code.  I know the data is valid because when I paste it [into this online converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), I get an image. I suspect there's some header data or something I need to add to convert it in my code, but I don't know what it is.  See complete code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageToByteArray
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //image to byteArray
            //Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\lorne\Downloads\radanmaster.bmp");
            //byte[] bArr = imgToByteArray(img);
            //byte[] bArr = imgToByteConverter(img);
            //Again convert byteArray to image and displayed in a picturebox

            string byteArrayString =
@"Qk2 + BwAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAAeAAAAHgAAAABAAEAAAAAAIAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA / +AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAf + AAAA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 / AQAEgAAAAAAAAAAACA
AfwAEABIAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAABAASAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAIAMgAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAACACIAAAA
AAAAAAABAAAAAAQBCAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAADBggAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAPgIAAAAAAAAAAACAAAA
AAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAACAAAAAAA
AAAABAAAAAAf//gAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAQ
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAf / gAAAAAAAAAA
ABAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAf//////8AA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA =";

            char[] charArray = byteArrayString.ToCharArray();
            byte[] bArr = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(charArray);

            Image img1 = byteArrayToImage(bArr);
            pictureBox1.Image = img1;
        }
        //convert image to bytearray
        public byte[] imgToByteArray(Image img)
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat);
                return mStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        //convert bytearray to image
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(mStream);
            }
        }
        //another easy way to convert image to bytearray
        public static byte[] imgToByteConverter(Image inImg)
        {
            ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(inImg, typeof(byte[]));
        }
    }
}
```

One thing I may possibly be doing wrong is I'm not exactly sure what all to extract from the XML file. See below for the complete XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadanCompoundDocument xmlns="http://www.radan.com/ns/rcd">
  <RadanAttributes>
    <Group class="system" name="System" desc="These attributes describe the Radan system used to create this file." ord="8">
      <Attr num="13" name="Language" desc="Radan language code." type="i" ord="1" value="0">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="14" name="Licence" desc="Radan licence code." type="s" ord="2" value="2961-1701-3233-9006-6060-8298">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="15" name="Build" desc="Radan software build." type="s" ord="3" value="2018.10.6">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Workflow state" desc="Attributes used for updating the workflow status" ord="14">
      <Attr num="16" name="Geometry time" desc="Time the geometry was last modified." type="t" ord="1">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="18" name="Tooling time" desc="Time the tooling was last modified." type="t" ord="3">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="system" name="File" desc="These attributes are basic properties of the file." ord="1">
      <Attr num="101" name="Created" desc="Time file was created." type="t" ord="3" value="2018-11-13T10:49:09-05:00">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="102" name="Modified" desc="Time file was last modified." type="t" ord="4" value="2018-11-13T10:49:09-05:00">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="103" name="File size" desc="File size in bytes." type="i" ord="5" value="17225">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="105" name="Associated files" desc="Associated files." type="s" ord="6">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="107" name="Extension" desc="File name extension." type="s" ord="2" value="sym">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="110" name="File name" desc="File name without its extension." type="s" ord="1" value="ST8042-08">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="141" name="Checkout user" desc="The username to which this file is checked out" type="s" ord="7">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="142" name="Checkout time" desc="The time at which this file was checked out" type="t" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="143" name="Filestore" desc="Radcontrol local filestore path" type="s" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="144" name="Current version" desc="A flag to show (when set to &quot;yes&quot;) that this is the current version of a file" type="s" ord="10">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Description" desc="Use these attributes to give a description of the file." ord="2">
      <Attr num="108" name="Title" desc="The title of this file." type="s" ord="1">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="109" name="Comments" desc="Comments about this file." type="s" ord="2">
        <Valid perm="e" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Manufacturing" desc="These attributes are the manufacturing properties of the file." ord="6">
      <Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1" value="Steel, Mild">
        <Valid perm="e" max="20" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="120" name="Thickness" desc="Thickness." type="r" ord="2" value="1.0">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="121" name="Thickness units" desc="Thickness units." type="s" ord="4" value="in">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="mm|in|swg" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="122" name="Orientation" desc="Allowed nest orientations (1=0°, 2=90°, 3=0/90°, 5=0/180°, 6=90/270°, 7=0/90/180/270°, 8=any)." type="i" ord="6">
        <Valid perm="e" min="1" max="8" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="127" name="Machine" desc="Machine name." type="s" ord="20">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="132" name="Mirror" desc="Whether the part can be mirrored in nesting." type="s" ord="7">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="139" name="STL id" desc="Standard Tool Loading file id." type="i" ord="21">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="145" name="Common cutting" desc="Whether the part is suitable for common line cutting in nesting." type="s" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="none|unrestricted|same part" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="146" name="Strategy" desc="Autotooling strategy." type="s" ord="22">
        <Valid perm="e" max="60" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="160" name="Picking cluster" desc="Whether to nest the part in clusters that are suitable for a part picker." type="s" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="164" name="Weight" desc="The weight of the part in lb or kg, depending on the geometry units attribute value." type="r" ord="5" value="0">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="181" name="Maximum CC group" desc="The maximum number of parts in a common cut group." type="i" ord="10">
        <Valid perm="e" min="2" max="999999" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="186" name="Workflow status" desc="The workflow status of this file." type="s" ord="29" value="1 - OK">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
        <MC machine="psys_Horst_6" value="1 - OK" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="196" name="Kit of parts" desc="Symbol is a kit of parts." type="s" ord="12">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Geometry" desc="These attributes are the geometry properties of the part." ord="5">
      <Attr num="162" name="Area" desc="The area of the part." type="r" ord="6" value="93.77751217">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="163" name="Area including holes" desc="The area of the part, ignoring any holes." type="r" ord="7" value="99.53981266">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="165" name="Bounding box X" desc="The maximum extent of the symbol's geometry in the X direction." type="r" ord="2" value="10.29302623">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="166" name="Bounding box Y" desc="The maximum extent of the symbol's geometry in the Y direction." type="r" ord="3" value="17.25818342">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="167" name="Outer perimeter" desc="The total length of all the lines and arcs in the outermost loop of the geometry only." type="r" ord="5" value="57.93457754">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="168" name="Perimeter" desc="The total length of all the lines and arcs in the geometry." type="r" ord="4" value="70.79983134">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="169" name="Geometry units" desc="The units in which the part's geometric attributes are measured." type="s" ord="1" value="in">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="mm|in|m|ft" max="80" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Cost estimate" desc="These attributes are used to estimate costs." ord="11">
      <Attr num="172" name="Last estimated cost" desc="The last estimated cost per item in run of quantity-off." type="r" ord="1">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="173" name="Setup cost" desc="The setting up component of the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="2">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="174" name="Runtime cost" desc="The runtime component of the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="3">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="175" name="Material cost" desc="The material component of the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="4">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="176" name="Last estimate sheet cost" desc="The cost of the sheet used in the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="5">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="177" name="Last estimate quantity" desc="The quantity used to produce the last cost estimate." type="i" ord="6">
        <Valid perm="e" min="1" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="178" name="Last estimate sheet X dimension" desc="The X dimension of the sheet used in the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="7">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="179" name="Last estimate sheet Y dimension" desc="The Y dimension of the sheet used in the last cost estimate." type="r" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="180" name="Last estimate sheet units" desc="The units of the dimensions of the sheet used in the last cost estimate." type="s" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="mm|inches" max="80" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Radbend" desc="These attributes record the file's Radbend properties." ord="12">
      <Attr num="197" name="3D bounding box X" desc="The X component of the 3D bounding box" type="r" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="198" name="3D bounding box Y" desc="The Y component of the 3D bounding box" type="r" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="199" name="3D bounding box Z" desc="The Z component of the 3D bounding box" type="r" ord="10">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="User" desc="You can use these attributes for your own purposes." ord="13">
      <Attr num="200" name="Part Description" type="s" ord="1" value="WOK Hitchplate">
        <Valid perm="e" max="200" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="300" name="User integer" type="i" ord="101">
        <Valid perm="e" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="400" name="User time" type="t" ord="201">
        <Valid perm="e" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="500" name="User real" type="r" ord="301">
        <Valid perm="e" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
  </RadanAttributes>
  <Thumbnail image-type="bmp" image-encoding="base64Binary"><![CDATA[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]]></Thumbnail>
  <RadanFile extension="ddc"><![CDATA[A,4,
B,D,>,,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:,<,=,>,
B,E,Z,?,@,E1,R1,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,k1,H,I,J,F1,;,K,L,:,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,<,=,>,U,m1,n1,52,62,:2,>2,?2,U2,V2,e2,
B,G,N,?,@,E1,R1,J,V,W,I,l1,O,P,Q,R,V1,W1,A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,O2,P2,Q2,R2,W2,[2,\2,
B,H,N,?,@,E1,R1,J,V,W,I,F,O,P,Q,R,S,T,X,Y,Z,[,V1,W1,A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,W2,
D,1,6,.4@0SIJFQY>8..3@7J=[A4ic6..4@0SIJFQY>8..3@7J=[A4ic6.3@9IVIVIVIV.o?0.o?0.$ST8042-08
E,,-1,R,,,,,,,1,1,1,,,1,,o?0...o?0.........o?0.o?0.$/
C,$
U,,$
U,$
U,,,,2,,,,
H,,1,1,,1,,,1,1,1@RGhemaOHH.1@>Jol1Pf4=.m?^_7GfbOV0.n?TLl7[i1^`..n?P.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,2,,1,,,1,,1@TBeCM<YF`.1@;gHK41]fG.1@2eaCnW^KP.3@P@QQ>ojHM.............,.,,,
H,,1,3,,1,,,1,1,m?W@ogY>^d0.2@RUFdknme^.n?0Y:A0h8Q0.m?VoVj8WbY0.m?>_7GfbOV0.l?1c`N_T6l0.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,4,,1,,,1,,l?42YDa34L0.2@SCF2`@=K0.0@6MC8LahDh.l?<^Mdi9L80.............,.,,,
H,,1,5,,1,,,1,1,0@7]M]_f4VX.2@RfWTkG3nh.o?=E6Y<eAk0.n?<F2]6h>_P.l?\\42KFl>0.0@6KJi[b;3\.o?0...o?0...........,
H,,1,6,,1,,,1,1,1@3<0Q;8Fb4.2@Q5?J6kS3j.m?5o?I\G:X0.o?72ah`eZN0.o?QSQ[N052P.o?0GG]?07g@.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,7,,1,,,1,,1@4SmNaicLT.1@\IbF1Y[PD.m?VkHInl<W0.o?3bB1f0Va@.............,.,,,
H,,1,8,,1,,,1,1,1@38?m9n2Z8.1@WM=eT9Qd0.n?W4474G350.e?T>VO1XU00.m?W3EQi5g\0.k?Z]X^7F:L0.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,9,,1,,,1,,1@0?_LAK:AP.1@WMR4:XSLU.m?S=k_T6:20.o?Pc9;IjimD.............,.,,,
H,,1,:,,1,,,1,,0@>5_JVESB`.1@[ZDG17Akj.0@PZB?C;:aP.m?6@KQl?eT`.o?PF3j0Idj0.m?2\ZP4Sh00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,;,,1,,,1,,o?:fjFVDa2P.1@ZABXiFBUW.l?1_><Z?j:0.0@59eB]kiOU.............,.,,,
H,,1,<,,1,,,1,,o?=4d8;V`C`.0@_H_o4`[[Y.k?32<P^L780.m?<Oc]SQ]iH.o??m<G]4^HP.k?ZblM8km0P.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,=,,1,,,1,,o?>@lj>PP`@.0@[daQHDMlN.0@0L81\6DoP.1@<_K@8TR9\.............,.,,,
H,,1,>,,1,,,1,1,0@?TVNcFUGX.0@=Z4nhdVFj.j?<fDmVHVh0.m?5V6\1K3H0.o?WD;>2MCkP.m?:[0I2_J?0.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,?,,1,,,1,,1@00^IhNNo@.1@0;Jj<OoHm.k?;NC<^P@<0.0@0HL^GkSWT.............,.,,,
H,,1,@,,1,,,1,1,1@0L<]5<o?L.1@8GYAHMa<_.i?^[H[?7600.j?0:O@>o?@0.i?^[H[?7600.e?9^F<WC<00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,A,,1,,,1,,1@0DQfjI=Ml.1@8O^Q0U@dG.0@V63^=_i1@.??0.............,.,,,
H,,1,B,,1,,,1,,o?55oo>53e@.1@8O^Q0U@dK.i?^^57[QB00.i?>^57[QA`0..i?>^57[QB00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,C,,1,,,1,,o?4WAj6IRS@.1@8WJ2BP98g..n?::7DGG7\@.............,.,,,
H,,1,D,,1,,,1,,o?4WAj6IRS@.1@;hZleK26I.i?>^57[QB00.i?>^57[QB00.i?>^57[QB00..o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,E,,1,,,1,,o?55oo>53e@.1@<0FN7EjJi.o?<i=0]iL\@.??X.............,.,,,
H,,1,F,,1,,,1,1,0@8oVOmo@@`.1@<0FN7EjJc.i?5^>Wkod@0.j?:>9gc`S00..i?>^57[QB00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,G,,1,,,1,,0@9:MWAm@:h.1@<=MS3?b\C.m?]J01NnT[0.m?=J01NnTZ0.............,.,,,
H,,1,H,,1,,,1,1,0@5O=W65KUP.1@>35S9;\nk.n?SE99l:7?P.k?7jHhE9580.n?SE99l:7?P.o?^PFLN[K[P.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,I,,1,,,1,,0@0YkDW2iaX.1@>Jol1Pf43.1@Z\fPABlA<.@?4.............,.,,,
G,,1,J,,1,,,1,,k?=BUU^IX80.1@0Y^4I:41g.i?VI>A4nf00.n?X4N1<VibH.............,.,,,
H,,1,K,,1,,,1,,k?7\B1M9jX0.0@;BDXO:IW8.i?_VHe?>500.i?]d770bQ\0.i?^]?n80C@0.d?<TKSVhb00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,L,,1,,,1,,j??UGXB\b`0.0@;3JTkZ0FB.0@P0f=1K:3X.j?=bo_Hc^:0.............,.,,,
H,,1,M,,1,,,1,,o?_2QZb@jQ`.0@;Q=T[2d4L.i?]d770bQ`0.i??VHe?>4X0.d?<TKSVh`00.i?>]?n80C80.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,N,,1,,,1,,o?_PEaiA]3P.0@;a0a5ZK6`.i?6I>A4nf00.n?84N1<VibX.............,.,,,
H,,1,O,,1,,,1,,o?_9lSX<^=P.1@0i48\J4a].i??VHe?>4`0.i?=d770bQh0.i?>]?n80C@0.d?\TKSVhX00.o?0...o?0...........,
G,,1,P,,1,,,1,,o?^ZF:bmP8`.1@10Q:N:AJ;.0@00f=1K:3`.j?]bo_Hc^<0.............,.,,,
H,,1,Q,,1,,,1,,k?5eScn<o\0.1@0aWZVMgS5.i?=d770bQ`0.i?_VHe?>4h0.d?\TKSVh`00.i?^]?n80C@0.o?0...o?0...........,
H,,1,R,,1,,,1,,0@=1]YR^QX8.1@0@LMQmZX=...o?R>ISQ=<LP.j?>T6m?<HH0.o?0...o?0...........,
]]></RadanFile>
  <History><![CDATA[_UPp
CF;F)iv B3?EpR$>4y0[@G Lpl_^WbEIlML9uuEJ\y
=G?(<3.R1_Tp7{"/.Hl;j%pO<;uMS>o93s7e,xmN+V
]]></History>
</RadanCompoundDocument>
```

Comment: It is a base64 string so use : Convert.FromBase64String(string)

Comment: That works, thanks!